# How can I load a project when the user hits the back button?

Tags: javascript

I have an application. When a user clicks "Add to Cart" or "Save Project" it calls the appropriate url to save the data and then redirects the user to the correct page:

```
      if (add_to_cart == true) //If we are adding to cart
      {
        $.ajax
        (
          {
            //Note: tf_cart.module must contain $_POST['app'] $jpg = xmlp_f_save_jpg($_POST['file'], $_POST['app']);
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            url:  SITE_URL + "/system/atc/" + app_type + "/0/" + session_id + "/0/?prjid=" + project_id, //send data to this url
            data: "xml=" + common_order_xml + "&prodid=" + product_id + "&file=" + image.src + "&rid=" + revision_id + "&cid=" + cart_id + "&app=html5" //send these as post variables to the url
          }
        ).done(function(msg) //When we get a response from the server after we POST
        {
          //console.log("Project added to cart. "); //This is for testing the canvas element on screen - leave this code here
          window.location = SITE_URL + "/cart/?pid=" + partner_id; //Send the user to the cart page
        });
      }
      else //If we are saving the project
      {
        $.ajax
        (
          {
            //Note: xmlproject.module must contain $_POST['app'] $jpg = xmlp_f_save_jpg( $_POST['file'], $_POST['app'] );
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            url:  SITE_URL + "/system/xml/import/" + app_type + "/" + session_id + "/?prjid=" + project_id, //send data to this url
            data: "xml=" + common_order_xml + "&prodid=" + product_id + "&file=" + image.src + "&app=html5&rid=" + revision_id //send these as post variables to the url
          }
        ).done(function(msg)  //When we get a response from the server after we POST
        {
          var parser = new DOMParser(); //create a new DOMParser
          var doc = parser.parseFromString(msg, "application/xml"); //convert the string to xml
          pid = doc.getElementsByTagName('pid')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; //Get the pid (project id) from the xml
          rid = doc.getElementsByTagName('rid')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; //Get the rid (revision id) from the xml
          //console.log("Project saved. " + " pid=" + pid + " rid=" + rid); //This is for testing the canvas element on screen - leave this code here
          window.location = SITE_URL + "/user/mystuff/projects/view/" + pid + "/?pid=" + partner_id; //Send the user to this project's page
        });
      }
```

The issue I have is once the user is either at the Project Page or the Cart page and they hit the back button, it returns them back to the application with a blank project. What I want to happen is when they hit the back button, that project gets loaded.

I'm not sure how to go about this... any ideas?

Comment: Maybe some manipulation of the history so you can somehow reference the project to be loaded?

Comment: At this point you may want to look into a framework. Backbone is pretty easy to apply to an existing project, and if you use its [router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) you get the functionality you're looking for out of the gate. However there's still the case of what happens if a user refreshes the page. Then you're SOL whatever you choose. You may want a localStorage solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem in a few different ways:

SOLUTION ONE (recommended imho): Along with updating your cart or saving your project, create a [session-cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) with the cart/project `pid`. If the users goes back to the application page (your main page?) check for the existence of this session and then reload or redirect to the cart/project.

SOLUTION TWO (a bit hackish): Instead of redirecting the user to the cart's/project's url, redirect him to an intermediate page. This page will again redirect the user ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)), but this time to the real cart/project page. When the user will press the back button he will go back and then forward, again to his cart/project page.

SOLUTION THREE: Use the [onbeforeunload](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp) event to warn the user and give him the chance to cancel his action of going back (this event fires whenever the user unloads the page and this is not a good solution imho).

SOLUTION FOUR: Use the HTML5 [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) in order to manipulate the user's browser history. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156939/how-to-handle-back-button-while-changing-the-browser-url-with-html5-pushstate) is some info that might help you. (I haven't tried this myself so i can't guarantee anything).

SOLUTION FIVE (a hybrid): If your website is more of an APP then you should consider using a whole other architecture and workflow. You can use a client-side javascript library for dynamic views and DOM manipulation, like [Google's AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [Facebook's React](http://facebook.github.io/react/). Don't direct the client to a new page everytime he needs to see new content (going from main page to cart page to project page, etc) because this is actually a complete page reload, and when the client goes back in history every page is again reloaded from scratch. Instead, use Ajax to load the new content (For example, a link like this `<a href="/cart/?pid">go to cart</a>` should be replaced with something like `<a href="#" onclick="loadCart(pid);">go to cart</a>`), the js libraries to update the page, and HTML5 [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to change the user's history state. Save the client's cart and project as a [session-cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) or on [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to quickly fetch this data whenever the client press 'back' or 'forward' buttons and then loading and showing him the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of my script, I check for the presence of the cookie, if it is there I delete the cookie (a new one will be generated if they save/add to cart again) and reload the page with the cookie information:

```
function common_init()
{
  var cookie = common_get_cookie("project_parameters");

  //Send the user back to the project they are working on when they hit the back button - AC 2014-12-04
  if ("" != cookie)
  {
    document.cookie = "project_parameters=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    window.location.href = (SITE_URL + "/Custom_App/?" + cookie);
  }
  //more code follows
}
```

and in the save project/add to cart function, I added:

```
document.cookie="project_parameters=app_type" + app_type + "&session_id=" + session_id + "&cart_id=" + cart_id + "&prjid=" + pid + "&rid=" + rid;
```